Join tables based on a range instead of exact match
I have two datasets as the ones described below:
dfA <- tibble(
  name = c("John", "Michael", "Brian", "Thomas", "Peter"),
  expected = c(128.34, 453.6674, 789.2345, 678.34, 475.467),
  max = c(128.3464, 453.6901, 789.2740, 678.3739, 475.4908),
  min = c(128.3336, 453.6447, 789.1950, 678.3061, 475.4432)
)

dfB <- tibble(
  real = c(128.76, 453.658, 789.235, 677.2035, 475.4695),
  time = c(3.24, 5.65, 4.89, 2.28, 6.12)
)

dfA$max and dfA$min have been previously calculated using the following functions:
shift <- function (theoretical, tolerance) {
  return(tolerance*theoretical/10^6)
}

calculate_max <- function (vector, tolerance) {
  res <- c()
  for (i in vector) {
    max <- i + shift(i, tolerance)
    res <- append(res, max)
  }
  return(res)
}

calculate_min <- function (vector, tolerance) {
  res <- c()
  for (i in vector) {
    min <- i - shift(i, tolerance)
    res <- append(res, min)
  }
  return(res)
}

I'd like to intersect both datasets so that dfB$real column lies between dfA$min and dfA$max columns.
I have already found a solution using the fuzzyjoin library, but I'm intrigued about how to do this manually, as iterating over rows with tibbles does not seem to be a good practice from what I've read and I cannot think of another way of achieving this without looping over rows.
The working solution with fuzzyjoin would be as follows (in case it's helpful to anyone):
fuzzy_right_join(dfB, dfA,
                 by = c("real"="max", "real"="min"),
                 match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`))

Thanks for your help!

Read about data.table foverlaps.

That's another option indeed, but I'd like to know how it would be possible to implement this manually. Specially since I will have to apply a more complicated constraint on the matches later...

"apply a more complicated constraint" - please add more details, and vote to re-open if the "merge on overlap" doesn't work in your case.

Why not just use left_join/right_join:
left_join(dfA, dfB, join_by(min <= real, max >= real))

# A tibble: 5 × 6
  name    expected   max   min  real  time
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 John        128.  128.  128.   NA  NA   
2 Michael     454.  454.  454.  454.  5.65
3 Brian       789.  789.  789.  789.  4.89
4 Thomas      678.  678.  678.   NA  NA   
5 Peter       475.  475.  475.  475.  6.12


Wow. That was an easy one. Didn't think of it. But anyway, I'd like to know how to implement this manually so that I can complicate a little bit more the constraints to match rows.

@jpm92 its unclear what you mean by complicate the constraints. Just use join_by(). Also you can write your code using for loop
